# PHP won't run on command line Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, php

I think I may just be missing something simple, but I can not get PHP to run anything on the command line. I'm using Linux Ubuntu.

All the exact same files run as expected via the web. I have tried all the following commands which produce blank. My php install is located in "/usr/bin/php"

I am logged in as root.

```
root@mydomain:~# whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib/php /usr/lib64/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

All return blank:

```
/usr/bin/php -v
/usr/bin/php -i
php -v
php -i
/usr/bin/php -v
echo "<?php echo \"hi\\n\";" | /usr/bin/php
echo "<?php echo \"hi\\n\";" | php
/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/delme.php
/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/delme.php
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a setting I must set in order to run a command from the cli? I've tried everything for the past 4 hours with no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

As requested by a user:

```
root@mydomain:~# ls -l /usr/bin/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar 17  2013 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php
root@mydomain:~# ls -l /etc/alternatives/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 17  2013 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php5
root@mydomain:~# ls -l /usr/bin/php5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 19 12:42 /usr/bin/php5

root@mydomain:/usr/bin# /usr/bin/php5 -v
root@mydomain:/usr/bin# 
root@mydomain:/usr/bin# type -a php
php is /usr/bin/php
```

Comment: Pleas post the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/php`.

Comment: root@mydomain:~# ls -l /usr/bin/php

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar 17  2013 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php

Comment: Ah, interesting, and what does `ls -l /etc/alternatives/php` show? Your `/usr/bin/php` is a link to it, does that file actually exist? It sounds like your webserver has a working PHP executable in it's path but you don't. You'll have to follow the symlinks until you find the missing one.

Comment: I see, here is the following (sorry about the formating)
root@mydomain:~# ls -l /etc/alternatives/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 17  2013 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php5
root@mydomain:~# ls -l /usr/bin/php5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 19 12:42 /usr/bin/php5

Comment: Please [edit] your question and @ping me to let me know. It is hard to read and easy to loose in the comments. While you're at it, please add the output of `/usr/bin/php5 -v`.

Comment: how strange...the following returns as expected! root@mydomain:/usr/bin# php5 | echo "hey";

Comment: OK, starting to understand. Could you add the output of `type -a php`?

Comment: output is: php is /usr/bin/php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12561/discussion-between-terdon-and-kirgy)

Comment: Please add the output of `file /usr/bin/php5`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `/usr/bin/php5` is empty, I assume you must have inadvertently overwritten it at some point. The easiest way to fix would be to remove `php` and reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5 && sudo apt-get install php5
```